# adding uiswich as navigation item

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uiswitch

in which way i can add programmatically an uiswitch as navigation items or btw on my navigation bar?
i'm going crazy :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: mySwitch] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UISwitch *foo = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:foo];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
[item release];
[foo release];
```